# How to display specific workspace to selected screen on i3 startup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, i3

I have 8 different workspaces defined in `~/.i3/config`:

```
set $workspace1_name 1:www
set $workspace2_name 2:programming
set $workspace3_name 3:communication
set $workspace4_name 4:files+dictionary
set $workspace5_name 5:documents
set $workspace6_name 6:graphics 
set $workspace7_name 7:virtualization
set $workspace8_name 8:music
```

I also have 2 screens. When I start i3 on my Linux start-up, each screen shows a different workspace. The right screen is showing workspace `2:programming`, but the left screen shows empty workspace `1` (not `1:www`).

How can I configure i3 so that the left screen shows properly named workspace `1:www` instead of `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#workspace_screen), the syntax is

```
workspace <workspace> output <output>
```

where `output` is the name of the RandR output you attach your screen to.

You can use one of the following RandR commands to get the `output` value

```
xrandr --current

# or if your X server supports RandR 1.5
xrandr --listmonitors
```

So, as an example (for my current dual screen set-up) the configuration should look like this

```
workspace "1: www" output DP-1
```

Comment: After setting `workspace $workspace1 output DP-2" i3 renders `1:www` workspace instead of `1` indeed. I used to have this line, but a bit different: `workspace 1 output DP-2` - using a variable (full name) fixed it. Thanks.